# Touch/Mouse Event behavour with listbox in WPF and Windows 8

Tags: wpf, vb.net, windows-8, mouseevent, touch-event

I am getting what I consider unexpected behaviour (since it differs from running the same software on windows 7) when trying to handle both mouse and touch inputs on a listbox on a windows 8 machine.

This is my function / method which is handling the events

```
Private Sub Drag_MouseDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Input.InputEventArgs) Handles lvItems.PreviewMouseDown, lvItems.PreviewTouchDown
```

When I have it handle both mouse and touch inputs, (`PreviewTouchDown` and `PreviewMouseDown`) it will receive both events (A touchevent and a mousebuttonevent), even though I set `event.Handled = True` on the `TouchEventArgs` for the event which is raised first.

If I remove the handling of the the PreviewTouchDown event from the event handler I then do not receive the PreviewMouseDown event.

What I need is for the method to only be called once per touch/click.  I cannot remove PreviewMouseDown because this is not only used with touch screens.  Having both the touch event and the mouse event passed for a single touch is breaking our functionality.

On windows 7 I receive only the touch events because I set handled=true so the mouse events are cancelled.

Comment: Why not just put all the functionality in `PreviewMouseDown` and leave `PreviewTouchDown` in there as a stub just to get `PreviewMouseDown` to fire?  Not ideal, but a possible workaround if you can't figure out what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

On windows 8, touch events can get promoted to mouse events. This is sometimes convenient, as it allows me to open a Combobox in Win8 (not under Win7) using touch, and sometimes this is undesired, as you discovered too. See also [JoshB's article](http://nui.joshland.org/2010/04/why-wont-wpf-controls-work-with-touch.html) for a more accurate explanation.

In my case, I checked in the mouse event handler whether e.StylusDevice == null (when dealing with a mouse, it is null, and not when dealing with a touch event). Maybe this helps you too?

For example, I made a ZoomGrid that listens to the mouse as well as touch. Under Windows 7, there was no problem, but under Windows 8, the pan behaviour got also triggered after a touchmove. Checking for e.StylusDevice != null fixed it.

```
    private void MainGridMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.LeftButton != MouseButtonState.Pressed) return;
        if (!isDraggingBackground || e.StylusDevice != null) return;
        var curPosition = e.GetPosition(sender as UIElement);
        var delta = curPosition - startPosition;
        var rectsMatrix = ((MatrixTransform)RenderTransform).Matrix;
        rectsMatrix.Translate(delta.X, delta.Y);
        Offset = new Point(rectsMatrix.OffsetX, rectsMatrix.OffsetY);
        RenderTransform = new MatrixTransform(rectsMatrix);
        e.Handled = true;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

What I did to solve this problem was detect if the computer was running Windows 8, and if so NOT setting `Handled` so that the mouse related event did not occur.

```
If Not My.Computer.Info.OSFullVersion.Contains("Windows 8") Then
    e.Handled = True
End If
```